# static inner class - weird

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

My code:

```
public class MyTest {
    public class StringSorter implements Comparator<String>
    {
        public StringSorter() {}

        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            int l1 = s1.length();
            int l2 = s2.length();
            return l1-l2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");

        StringSorter sorter = new StringSorter();
        Set<String> sets = new TreeSet<String>(sorter);
        sets.add(new String("he"));
        sets.add(new String("hel"));
        sets.add(new String("he"));
        sets.add(new String("hello"));

        for (String s: sets)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

It will complain an error:
"MyTest.java:41: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Remove this line will pass compile. However, we need many String objects in the 'static main' method. What's the difference between String and StringSorter?

If I  change StringSorter to be static inner class, it will be compiled OK. How does static inner class fix the compile error?

Comment: You should use just "he" instead of new String("he")

Comment: Why?^^ Thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringSorter` is an inner class and is always 'bound' to an instance of the outer class `MyTest` (it can access its members, call its methods etc...) . Since you try to instantiate it from a static context (the static main method) it fails. Instead you can make the inner class static (like `static public class StringSorter`) to make it work.

Alternatively you can move `StringSorter` outside of `MyTest` in which case they are seperate classes. (If you want to still keep both classes within the same file, you have to remove the `public` modifier, since only a single public class - with the name of the file - is allowed per source file).

Another alternative would be to move your 'test code' from the main method into some member method of `MyTest` (therefore non-static context) and call this method...

Comment: I don't understand your last proposition. A non-static method of MyTest couldn't be called from the main method, which is static.

Comment: What I meant: move all the code from `main` to some method `test()` in `MyTest`, and write in `MyTest.main`: `new MyTest().test()` ...

Comment: Ok, it was not clear to me. This way, you can instanciate a `Mytest` object, and so call instanciate nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

As dcn has said, you have to add the `static` keyword to the `StringComparator` (see below):

```
public static class StringSorter implements Comparator<String>
```

Inner classes are usually **static**, because they normally are **utility classes** (the same in your case; `StringComparator` helps you to compare strings based on their lenght).

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) explains quite well how to deal with inner classes. In your code, you're trying to use `MyTest.StringSorter` from your main method. `MyTest.main` is static, so it can't access the non-static fields, methods, inner classes that are defined in its outer calss.

When making `StringSorter` static, this inner class can be called from the static methods of the outer class.

When you call your original code, you're not working with an instance of `MyTest`. You're using one of its static method. it is said in the tutorial that :

> An instance of InnerClass can exist
>   only within an instance of OuterClass
>   and has direct access to the methods
>   and fields of its enclosing instance.

Hope it's clearer now ;-)